# React Private Route Validation using API Authentication

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I've been trying to make a private route for admin page.

For my router this is my code:

```
<React.Fragment>
  <Switch>
    <Route path='/' component={Home} exact>
      <Home />
    </Route>
    <Route path='/data' component={Data}>
      <Data />
    </Route>
    <ProtectedRoute path='/admin' component={Admin} />
  </Switch>
</React.Fragment>
```

And then for my ProtectedRoute Component, this is what I have:

```
if (Authenticated() === 200) {
  return <Route path={props.path} component={props.component} />;
} else {
  return <Redirect to='/' />;
}
```

And then for Authenticated function, I have:

```
function Authenticated() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState('');

  axios.get('/users').then((res) => {
    setAuth(res.status);
  });

  return auth;
}
```

My problem is that react returns the auth as empty string and then returns another one as 200. The condition in ProtectedRoute is not waiting for the final value of the auth thus it is always going to the else statement.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seem to be coming from your `Autheticated` function returning mutiple outcomes for a single call.

A quick fix i would suggest is checking for failure instead of `else`

```
if (Authenticated() === 200) {
  return <Route path={props.path} component={props.component} />
}

if (Authenticated() === 401) {
  return <Redirect to='/' />
}
```

this avoids `<Redirect to='/' />` until you are sure authentication has failed

for the double calls, if you post the code from your `Authenticated` function you might get help with preventing it from returning empty string.